# pandas: Validating data frame cells using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

I have a non-indexed data frame with over 50000 lines read from a csv file as follows:

```
John   Mullen  12/08/1993  Passw0rd
Lisa   Bush    06/12/1990  myPass12
Maria  Murphy  30/03/1989  qwErTyUi
Seth   Black   21/06/1991  LoveXmas
```

I would like to validate each cell of each row against a specific **regular expression**:

- validate the password with the `PassRegex` below
- validate First name/ last Name with the `NameRegex` below
- etc...

and then move the rows where any of the cells do not validate to a new data frame.

```
import re
PassRegex = re.compile(r"^(?!.*\s)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,50}$")
NameRegex = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-]{2,80}$")
```

For example in this case, the below rows wouldn't validate with the PassRegex, so I want to move them to a  separate data frame:

```
Maria  Murphy  30/03/1989  qwErTyUi
Seth   Black   21/06/1991  LoveXmas
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating through the whole data frame row by row, and cell by cell?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the regex to [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [36]:
passRegex = r"^(?!.*\s)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,50}$"
nameRegex = r"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-]{2,80}$"
df[(df['password'].str.contains(passRegex, regex=True)) & (df['first'].str.contains(nameRegex, regex=True)) & (df['last'].str.contains(nameRegex, regex=True))]

Out[36]:
  first    last         dob  password
0  John  Mullen  12/08/1993  Passw0rd
1  Lisa    Bush  06/12/1990  myPass12
```

To only keep the rows of interest, this creates a boolean mask for each condition and uses `&` to `and` them together, you need parentheses due to operator precedence

The output from each condition:

```
In [37]:
df['password'].str.contains(passRegex, regex=True)

Out[37]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: password, dtype: bool

In [38]:
df['first'].str.contains(nameRegex, regex=True)

Out[38]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: first, dtype: bool

In [39]:
df['last'].str.contains(nameRegex, regex=True)

Out[39]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: last, dtype: bool
```

And then when we combine them:

```
In [40]:
(df['password'].str.contains(passRegex, regex=True)) & (df['first'].str.contains(nameRegex, regex=True)) & (df['last'].str.contains(nameRegex, regex=True))

Out[40]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hey @EdChum, sorry to be coming so late to this question, but if I want to get this regex from a text file and use it in my code, then how would we do that? Substitution with `%s` is not working for me :(

Comment: @ManasJani Please post a new question with your raw data, code to recreate your df, the desired output ,and your attempts. Answering questions via comments is counter-productive

Comment: Already posted this question a few days ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53711128/substitute-a-string-from-a-file-into-python-code